# Move text without increasing size of div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and I am trying to figure out how to move text in a div element without increasing the size of the div. I tried using padding, but other text got misaligned because of it (Activity log gets moved down).

I am trying to centrally align the text under current status and only make the text "Current Status" and "Activity Log" in bold and not the text below them.

```js
$(function updat() {
  var url = "https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var humid = [],
    date = [],
    high=[],
    day=[],
    chanceOfRain=[],
    humid_final = [],
    day_final=[],
    high_final=[],
    chanceOfRain_final=[],
    Itemss=[],
    SortedItems=[]
    var htmlText='';

  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    $(json['Items']).each(function(i, data) {
      //Store indicator name
      
      // fill the date array
      humid.push(data.humidity);
      // fill the string data array 
      date.push(data.Date);

      high.push(data.high);
      day.push(data.Day);
      chanceOfRain.push(data.chanceOfRain);

    });

    //unsorted array
    Itemss=$(json['Items']);
    //console.log("ITEMS",Itemss);

    //sorted array- date
     date.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

    // Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return  date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});

     console.log("Sorted Days", date);
    Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});
     console.log(" Sorted ITEMS",Itemss);
    ////////

    // query send string that we need to convert into numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < humid.length; i++) {
      if (humid[i] != null) {
        humid_final.push(parseFloat(humid[i]));
        high_final.push(parseFloat(high[i]));
        day_final.push(parseFloat(day[i]));
        chanceOfRain_final.push(parseFloat(chanceOfRain[i]));
      } else {
       humid_final.push(null)
      };
    }

    //sorting the arrays
    day_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
   // console.log("Sorted day_final", day_final);

    humid_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});


    //ACTIVITY LOG
    var h1 = [10, 20, 30, 40,50,60];
    var t1 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    var activ= document.querySelector('.activ');
    for(var i=0; i<h1.length;i++){
      activ.innerHTML += `<p>Temperature was ${t1[i]} degrees and humidity was ${h1[i]} % `;
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.chart({

       credits: {
      enabled: false
        },
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'light',
        marginBottom: 100
      },
      title: {
        text: ' Ambient Light'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'light level',
        data: high_final, //
        color: '#9b0000' 
      }]
    });


var chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
       credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'temp&humid',
        marginBottom: 100
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature and Humidity'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
       name: 'Temperature',
        data: chanceOfRain_final,
        color:'#646569' //
      },
      {
        type:'line',
        name:'Humidity',
        data: day_final,
        color:'#c5050c' 
      }]
    });

var chart2=  Highcharts.chart('stacked', {

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      height: 250,
      width: 400,
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Today's Light and Water Sources"
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Water', 'Light']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Natural',
        data: [7 , 6],
        color:'#c5050c'
    }, {
        name: 'Automatic',
        data: [ 3, 4],
        color: '#646569'
    }]
});


  }); //getJSON method
  //setTimeout(updat, 3000);

});


$(function dat() {
 // console.log("here");
  var url="https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var htmlText='';

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {


});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src= "Ag.js"></script>

<div id="light" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="temp&humid" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="stacked"> </div>

<div id="parentContainer" style="margin-left:400px; width: 200px; margin-top: -20%" >

 <div id="currentSatus"><center><b>Current Status<b><center></div>
 <br>
 <div id="temp" style=" background: #72D923;height: 50px"><font face='verdana'><center>Temperature<center></font> </div>
 <div id="hum" style="background: red; height: 50px"><font face='verdana'><center>Humidity<center></font></div>
 <div id="water" style="background:#72D923; height: 50px "><font face='verdana'><center>Water</center></font></div>
 <div id="ligh" style="background: red; height: 50px"><font face='verdana'><center>Light</center></font></div>
 </div>

<div class=" activ" id="log" style="margin-left: 600px; text-align: center; margin-top: -18.5%"><center>Activity Log</center> </div>
```

Comment: I tried playing with it a little, but noticed that based on the code above it acts differently depending on window size.

Comment: I just want it to act fine when viewed full screen

Comment: Can you word this sentence better please? "I am trying to centrally align the text under current status and only make the text "Current Status" and "Activity Log" and not the text below them."

Comment: @Ragxion, I mean to have the text, in the green/red boxes under "Current Status" to be in the center of the respective red/green box and only have the  "Current Status" and "Activity Log" texts in bold .

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  You may want to consider some editor when coding html/css (one of my favorites is sublime).  What I noticed and the only real take-away from this answer should be the tags were not being closed when they are opened.  I noticed it with the `<b>` tag and `<center>` tags in the second section.

```js
$(function updat() {
  var url = "https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var humid = [],
    date = [],
    high=[],
    day=[],
    chanceOfRain=[],
    humid_final = [],
    day_final=[],
    high_final=[],
    chanceOfRain_final=[],
    Itemss=[],
    SortedItems=[]
    var htmlText='';

  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    $(json['Items']).each(function(i, data) {
      //Store indicator name
      
      // fill the date array
      humid.push(data.humidity);
      // fill the string data array 
      date.push(data.Date);

      high.push(data.high);
      day.push(data.Day);
      chanceOfRain.push(data.chanceOfRain);

    });

    //unsorted array
    Itemss=$(json['Items']);
    //console.log("ITEMS",Itemss);

    //sorted array- date
     date.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

    // Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return  date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});

     console.log("Sorted Days", date);
    Itemss.sort(function(a,b){return date.indexOf(a.Date)<date.indexOf(b.Date)?-1:1});
     console.log(" Sorted ITEMS",Itemss);
    ////////

    // query send string that we need to convert into numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < humid.length; i++) {
      if (humid[i] != null) {
        humid_final.push(parseFloat(humid[i]));
        high_final.push(parseFloat(high[i]));
        day_final.push(parseFloat(day[i]));
        chanceOfRain_final.push(parseFloat(chanceOfRain[i]));
      } else {
       humid_final.push(null)
      };
    }

    //sorting the arrays
    day_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
   // console.log("Sorted day_final", day_final);

    humid_final.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});


    //ACTIVITY LOG
    var h1 = [10, 20, 30, 40,50,60];
    var t1 = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    var activ= document.querySelector('.activ');
    for(var i=0; i<h1.length;i++){
      activ.innerHTML += `<p>Temperature was ${t1[i]} degrees and humidity was ${h1[i]} % `;
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.chart({

       credits: {
      enabled: false
        },
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'light',
        marginBottom: 100
      },
      title: {
        text: ' Ambient Light'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'light level',
        data: high_final, //
        color: '#9b0000' 
      }]
    });


var chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
       credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'temp&humid',
        marginBottom: 100
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature and Humidity'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: day_final //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
       name: 'Temperature',
        data: chanceOfRain_final,
        color:'#646569' //
      },
      {
        type:'line',
        name:'Humidity',
        data: day_final,
        color:'#c5050c' 
      }]
    });

var chart2=  Highcharts.chart('stacked', {

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      height: 250,
      width: 400,
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Today's Light and Water Sources"
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Water', 'Light']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Natural',
        data: [7 , 6],
        color:'#c5050c'
    }, {
        name: 'Automatic',
        data: [ 3, 4],
        color: '#646569'
    }]
});


  }); //getJSON method
  //setTimeout(updat, 3000);

});


$(function dat() {
 // console.log("here");
  var url="https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var htmlText='';

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {


});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src= "Ag.js"></script>

<div id="light" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="temp&humid" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; left:10px"></div>
<div id="stacked"> </div>

<div id="parentContainer" style="margin-left:400px; width: 200px; margin-top: -20%" >

 <div id="currentSatus"><center><b>Current Status</b></center></div>
 <br>
 <div id="temp" style=" background: #72D923;height: 50px "><font face='verdana'><center>Temperature</center></font> </div>
 <div id="hum" style="background: red; height: 50px"><font face='verdana'><center>Humidity</center></font></div>
 <div id="water" style="background:#72D923; height: 50px "><font face='verdana'><center>Water</center></font></div>
 <div id="ligh" style="background: red; height: 50px"><font face='verdana'><center>Light</center></font></div>
 </div>

<div class=" activ" id="log" style="margin-left: 600px; text-align: center; margin-top: -18.5%"><center>Activity Log</center> </div>
```